# How to do inner join on separate angular firestore collections?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm currently trying to build a website where users can specify what data they'd like to see using 4 separate filters (e.g. type, location, etc). I originally had an issue with using multiple 'in' or 'array-contains-any' operators when trying to query my firebase, as I was only allowed to use one of them once (e.g. I couldn't do where type in x, where location in y, and so on).

Due to this, my idea was to separate these queries up, have each filter query the firebase by itself, and do an inner join of all these collections into one that has the correct data (e.g. One that has all opportunities that are of type x, from location y, with requirements z). However, I'm unfortunately not sure how to do a inner join of these 3 different collections. I would appreciate any help if possible

```
    // Step 1: Filter by the type of the opportunity
    if (isFilterType){
      this.typeColl = this.afs.collection<Opportunity>('opportunities', ref => ref.where('oppoType','in',oppoType))
    }

    // Step 2: Filter by the location of the opportunity itself
    if (isFilterLocation){
      this.locationColl = this.afs.collection<Opportunity>('opportunities', ref => ref.where('location','in',location))
    }

    // Step 3: Filter by the requirements that the opportunity has
    if (isFilterRequirements){
      this.requirementsColl = this.afs.collection<Opportunity>('opportunities', ref => ref.where('requirements','array-contains-any',requirements))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't have an inner join type query.  You have to write code on the client to merge the results of all of these queries as you see fit.  This means you will have to read every document in all the queries and figure out how the final joined data structure should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug Stevenson pointed out Firestore doesn't have an inner join query, therefore to follow this idea you have to write your own merging code.

However your original attempt was applying several filter clauses to the Opportunity collection and you could implement that right away. An approach might be the following: Make one of your three queries (for efficiency choose the one that will return the least documents), then filter to prune out documents that don't match the desired value of the other fields. Since you're retrieving documents from the same collection the idea of Inner Join as usually understood in SQL settings is an overwork for this use case.

You could also take a look at [composite indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) which directly allow queries based on more than one field.